# Meteor loading data with React Komposer

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to load data using React Komposer and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, pretty sure this is the way it should be unless I miss something. But I'm not getting any data in the UI. Could use the help

container.js

```
import { composeWithTracker } from 'react-komposer';
import RightNavBar from './right-nav-bar.jsx';

function composer(props, onData) {
    const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('currentUser');
    const currentUser = 'bbbb';
    onData(null, currentUser);
}
export default composeWithTracker(composer)(RightNavBar);
```

My component

```
export class RightNavBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                aaaa {currentUser}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: And what if `currentUser` was an object rather than a string?

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: I did, I need to answer it. The issue was due to incorrect imports

Comment: There were multiple issues...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "standard" example from [react-komposer's repository](https://github.com/kadirahq/react-komposer#using-with-meteor) (adapted to your specific case)

```js
function composer(props, onData) {
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('currentUser');
  if (subscription.ready()) {
    const currentUser = Meteor.user(); //or whatever
    onData(null, {currentUser});
  };
};
```

Here you subscribe and when the subscription is ready, your component is rendered. Otherwise, a `loading` component is rendered.

The 2nd parameter to `onData` should be an object. It is merged with other `props` passed to your component and is accessible from within your component via `this.props`.

From within your component,the `props` object is available via `this.props`, so you can either deconstruct it or access its properties directly.

```js
class RightNavBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {currentUser} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        Hello, {currentUser.name}!
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Your code sends a string rather than an object and React has no way of making sense of the token `currentUser` from within your component.

Comment: So I just tested this and added console.log(currentUser); right after const but I'm getting undefined

Comment: What are you passing to the component? You should add the query that fetches the data that you desire. If the user is not logged in, `Meteor.user()` will, obviously, be `undefined`.

Comment: User is logged in, but I also tested it like so  const currentUser = {data:'test'}; and still undefined. The data is not getting passed to the component. Is there an issue if the component is embed inside another component? I have header component which has left nav component and right nav bar component

Comment: Yeah, you should pass the desired data to the child component.

Comment: I just tested it by trying to top component header and I'm still not getting the data. Any ideas? I'm using flow router with react mount and mounting all my templates via flower router but I don't think that is the issue

Comment: Start by using a single, simple component that is similar to the one in the answer code and we'll take it from there. Also, log the data being sent to the component in the composer itself, to see if you send anything at all.

Comment: Ok did that, getting something weird let me explain in my right nav bar component inside the render console.log(this.props); I get Object {} and if I do console.log(currentUser); I get undefined remember I have const {currentUser} = this.props; at the  top

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126889/discussion-between-masteram-and-almog-koren).

Comment: I also moved the following out of the if statement to check if the sub was the issue const currentUser = {data:'test'}; onData(null, {currentUser}); still getting undefined